# Transferring a Large Collection of Small-size Files

Tags: ftp, apache-flink, apache-nifi, file-transfer, data-stream

The usual methods of transferring data (scp, http and ftp utilities such as curl or wget) work fine when your data is in the MB or even GB range, but when you have very large collections of small-size files (e.g 10KB) there, it will be very slow to transfer and the bandwidth is not used at all.

There are two servers (S1,S2) when one file is recieved in S1 then it should send it to S2 immediately.

Do you have any idea about using some DSP tools for example Apache Flink or NIFI?

Comment: I suspect there is some aspect of your question that I am missing, but normally when you have many small files, you either `tar`/`zip` them together to avoid the *"per-file"* overhead, or you run multiple, parallel streams to use the available bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used `Apache-Flink` but 
Using **NiFi** this usecase is fairly simple (just drag,drop and configure 3 processors)

**Flow:**

```
1.ListFile //list files in S1 server
    --> Success Connection (Load Balance Strategy (or) Remote Processor Group)
2.FetchFile //fetch the file from S1 Server
    --> Success Connection
3.PutFile //send the file to S2 server
```

- We are going to run **`ListFile/ListSFTP..etc`** processor all the time to incrementally lists the files in the directory.
- Once we have listed the files we can do `load balance and distribute` the work across all nodes in the cluster
- Actual Fetching of the files will be done by **`FetchFile`** processor dynamically based on the **attributes** associated with the flowfile.
- Use the `success` connection from **`FetchFile`** processor to transfer the file to **S2 Sever** using **`PutFile/PutSFTP..etc`** processor.

Please refer to [this](https://pierrevillard.com/2018/10/29/nifi-1-8-revolutionizing-the-list-fetch-pattern-and-more/) link for more details/usage of the above flow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flink to continuously copy files, yes - though that's not a use case I've typically seen, as all you're doing is moving bytes, versus processing the data data (which is where Flink does best).

To do this with Flink, you'd set up a [`(Rich)SourceFunction`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/source/RichSourceFunction.html) that continuously monitors the S3 source directory, and emits the path to any new file.  Then you'd likely use an [`AsyncFunction`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/stream/operators/asyncio.html#asynchronous-i-o-for-external-data-access) to do async copying of the file from the current to the new location.

-- Ken